# Entry source Journey builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I 'm creating my first journey and I 'm confused on how/which should be the entry source. 
I have three DE linked in an attribute group called Abandoned Cart. One DE store contacts, another the Abandoned Cart and the last one the items of the abandoned cart. When the attribute status in Abandoned cart DE assume the value "on hold" , the journey should start. I other words:
-Contacts should enter the journey when the fields Status in the DE Abandoned Cart is equal to "on hold"; 
- for each cart (there is an attribute called cartID) they should enter the journey only once
- but they can enter again in the journey if the cart ID is another.
I can't figure out how to design the entry source and I hope someone is able to help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am assuming, you have the relationship keys to connect your 3 dots (contact, abandon cart & product). Use the SQL query to connect these 3 dots via JOIN function in SQL query an use update action to upsert the records in a data extension and use primary key as Cart ID. This will solve your problem on enter again in the journey if the cart ID is another.

Reference - https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/marketing-cloud-data-management/query-data-with-sql

Once you have done that you can use this data extension as a source of entry event and send out an email. In the journey setting you can set the option as 'No re-entry'. This will solve your problem on entering the journey only once.

Reference - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_journey_settings.htm&type=5

Let me know if this helps.